# TfsBuild does not run unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, tfsbuild

I'm using tfs 2010 and I want to create a tfsbuild defintion that runs unit tests.

1. I created unit tests and it works perfectly on my local machine.
2. I created a build definition, enabled tests, opened automated tests and put the vsmdi file.

the build succeed but it does not run any tests. In the build log file I don't find any information about the number of tests ran, it just tell me no test results ,besides the TestResults Directory is empty.

Has any one an idea.

Comment: Are you using VS 2010 MSTest framework (the one that is built into VS 2010)?  Note: VS2012 tests won't work on a TFS2010 build server

Comment: Also try running the build with Verbosity=Diagnostic and examining the detailed build log to see what happened.

Comment: Yes I'm using MSTest framework. I changed the verbosity to diagnostic but still not having any information about tests.

Comment: I found this warning in the log file: Target "ResolveTestReferences" skipped due to false condition ('@(Shadow)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the Problem. The build platform is x86 but for the test project it's AnyCPU, that's why tfsbuild did not execute tests.

Comment: And what was the solution?

Comment: I just changed the Project platform to x86.